# How can I show an animation for 3 seconds before loading the page?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to show an animation before the website's content is displayed. I tried it myself and then saw some videos, but the videos show how to deliver the loader when the website is loading.

I want to show the animation irrespective of the loading. How can I do this?

This is the .jsx file and then the following is the CSS file.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import './home.css'
import video from './A.mp4';
import video1 from './Ankit.mp4';
import img1 from './home1.jpeg';
import img2 from './home4.jpeg';
import img3 from './home3.jpeg';
import { faDisplay } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function Home() {
    const about = useRef(null);
    const work = useRef(null);
    const contact = useRef(null);

    const scrollSection = (elementRef) => {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: elementRef.current.offsetTop,
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    };
    const alerting = () => {
        window.alert('Adding soon');
    }
    let preloder = document.getElementsByClassName('logo_video2');
    const showlogo = () =>{
        preloder.style.display = 'none';
    }
    return (
        <>

        <video loop autoPlay muted playsInline className='logo_video2' >
                            <source src={video1} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
```

Now, this is the CSS part for the same query.

```css
.logo_video2{
    position: fixed;
    width:  200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 35%;
    right: 25%;
    background: black url('./Ankit.mp4') no-repeat center;
    z-index: 98798798 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a state variable that is set to true and then set it to false after 3 seconds and conditionally render your video component accordingly.

Please find the required code here.

```js
export default function Home() {
    const [showVideo, setShowVideo] = useState(true);
    const about = useRef(null);
    const work = useRef(null);
    const contact = useRef(null);
    useEffect(
    () => {
      let timer1 = setTimeout(() => setShowVideo(false), 3000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer1);
      };
    },
    []
  );
    return (
        <>

       {showVideo ? <video loop autoPlay muted playsInline className='logo_video2' >
                            <source src={video1} type="video/mp4" />
        </video> : <YourOtherComponent />}

}
```